# Aesthetics not right, might be related to melt function

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series

I have the following task: 
-Extrect 2 tabs from an URL Excel file (contain hourly data)
-In one tab I am only interested in the data point at 16:00, and hence filter for it
-In the second tab I am interested in all data points, but to be aligned, I create a daily average of the 24 hourly values

Then, I use some sort of cbind.fill function because I want to merge the data. This is necessary, as I get my 16:00 only at 16:00 of course and couldnt use CBIND before 16:00 as I would have one less line as I have in the aggregated tab.

Then I do some variable filtering and renaming.

Before plotting I use the melt function in order to create some sort of subchart. Here might lie the problem, I also get a warning when running the code. I don't understand why but I struggle to convert the levels from factors to numerical characters.

I can still plot in the end but the x axis looks hideous. It is actually not such a difficult task but I am getting nowhere. If you could give me a hint, I'd appreciate it.

Thanks in advance!

The code:

```
is.installed <- function(mypkg){
  is.element(mypkg, installed.packages()[,1])
} 
if (!is.installed("ggplot2")){
  install.packages("ggplot2")
}
if (!is.installed("lubridate")){
  install.packages("lubridate")
}
if (!is.installed("openxlsx")){
  install.packages("openxlsx")
}
library(ggplot2)
library(lubridate)
library(openxlsx)
library(reshape2)
library(dplyr)

Storico_G <- read.xlsx(xlsxFile = "http://www.snamretegas.it/repository/file/Info-storiche-qta-gas-trasportato/dati_operativi/2017/DatiOperativi_2017-IT.xlsx",sheet = "Storico_G", startRow = 1, colNames = TRUE)

Storico_G1 <- read.xlsx(xlsxFile = "http://www.snamretegas.it/repository/file/Info-storiche-qta-gas-trasportato/dati_operativi/2017/DatiOperativi_2017-IT.xlsx",sheet = "Storico_G+1", startRow = 1, colNames = TRUE)

# Selecting Column C,E,R from Storico_G and stored in variable Storico_G_df
# Selecting Column A,P from Storico_G+1 and stored in variable Storico_G1_df

Storico_G_df <- data.frame(Storico_G$pubblicazione,Storico_G$IMMESSO, Storico_G$`RICONSEGNATO.(1)`, Storico_G$BILANCIAMENTO.RESIDUALE )
Storico_G1_df <- data.frame(Storico_G1$pubblicazione, Storico_G1$`SBILANCIAMENTO.ATTESO.DEL.SISTEMA.(SAS)`)


# Conerting pubblicazione in date format and time
Storico_G_df$pubblicazione <- ymd_h(Storico_G_df$Storico_G.pubblicazione)
Storico_G1_df$pubblicazione   <- ymd_h(Storico_G1_df$Storico_G1.pubblicazione)


# Selecting on row which is having 4PM value in Storico_G+1 excel sheet tab
Storico_G1_df <- subset(Storico_G1_df, hour(Storico_G1_df$pubblicazione) == 16)
rownames(Storico_G1_df) <- 1:nrow(Storico_G1_df)

# Averaging hourly values to 1 daily data point in G excel sheet tab
Storico_G_df$Storico_G.pubblicazione <- strptime(Storico_G_df$Storico_G.pubblicazione, "%Y_%m_%d_%H")
storico_G_df_agg <- aggregate(Storico_G_df, by=list(day=format(Storico_G_df$Storico_G.pubblicazione, "%F")), FUN=mean, na.rm=TRUE)[,-2]

#cbind.fill function
cbind.fill <- function(...){
    nm <- list(...) 
    nm <- lapply(nm, as.matrix)
    n <- max(sapply(nm, nrow)) 
    do.call(cbind, lapply(nm, function (x) 
        rbind(x, matrix(, n-nrow(x), ncol(x))))) 
}

#cbind with both frames
G_G1_df= data.frame(cbind.fill(storico_G_df_agg,Storico_G1_df))

#keep required columns
keep=c("Storico_G.IMMESSO","Storico_G..RICONSEGNATO..1..","Storico_G1..SBILANCIAMENTO.ATTESO.DEL.SISTEMA..SAS..")

#update dataframe to kept variables
G_G1_df=G_G1_df[,keep,drop=FALSE]

#add counting variable
G_G1_df$X=seq(nrow(G_G1_df))

#Rename crazy variable names
G_G1_df <- data.frame(G_G1_df) %>% 
     select(Storico_G.IMMESSO, Storico_G..RICONSEGNATO..1.., Storico_G1..SBILANCIAMENTO.ATTESO.DEL.SISTEMA..SAS.., X)
names(G_G1_df) <- c("Immesso","Riconsegnato", "SAS","X")

#Melt time series
G_G1_df=melt(G_G1_df,id.vars = "X")

#Create group variable
G_G1_df$group<- ifelse(G_G1_df$variable == "SAS", "SAS", "Immesso/Consegnato")

#plot
ggplot(G_G1_df, aes(X,value, col=variable))+geom_point()+geom_line()+facet_wrap(~group,ncol=1,scales="free_y")+geom_abline(intercept=c(-2,0,2),slope=0,data=subset(G_G1_df,group=="SAS"),lwd=0.5,lty=2)
```

Comment: I ran G_G1_df$value <- as.numeric(G_G1_df$value) before the ggplot and it works fine

Comment: Thank you v much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leaving aside the data wrangling part (that can surely be vastly improved) the plot problem lies in the fact that the `value` column is of `character` class. (This cames from the data wrangling part)

As a simple solution you can just cast it to numeric in the `ggplot` call:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(G_G1_df, aes(X,as.numeric(value), col=variable))+
    geom_point()+
    geom_line()+
    facet_wrap(~group,ncol=1,scales="free_y")+
    geom_abline(intercept=c(-2,0,2),slope=0,data=subset(G_G1_df,group=="SAS"),lwd=0.5,lty=2)
#> Warning: Removed 1 rows containing missing values (geom_point).
#> Warning: Removed 1 rows containing missing values (geom_path).
```

[image]